# Swift Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segmentation-fault, swift3

I am trying to do **Product**->**Archive** in `Xcode`, but I get this error.

> "1.    While running pass #317664 SILFunctionTransform "Constant Propagation" on SILFunction "@_TTSg5VSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyS_s8Hashable5UIKit_P__CSo8NSObjectS2_S0_10ObjectiveC_Ps9AnyObject____TFs17_dictionaryUpCastu2_Rxs8Hashable0_S_rFGVs10Dictionaryxq__GS0_q0_q1__"."

When I try to build I have no errors, but when I try to archive the console I see this error.

I'm using `Swift 3`.

The full console report can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/XszjujYj).

Comment: Did you try to do Product/Clean, shutdown XCode, delete derived data, and retry?  Sometimes this helps with "weird" crashes.

Comment: did you figure this out? had the same issue today when archiving but was successful when building and running

Comment: the same. Only while archiving Xcode 8.1

Comment: @JulioVasquez in case you need a solution

Comment: @protspace in case you need a solution

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I don't know if you guys solved this yet but I had the exact same problem, tried clean delete derived data and everything, was able to build but not archive and got the same error. The way I solved it was to disable Swift Complier Optimization for Release in build settings, I attached an image of what it looks like afterward.

[Disable Swift Complier Optimization for Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCfor.png)